# When I edit a comment on Facebook or Instagram do the people tagged on the edit get notified because of it?

Tags: facebook, instagram

Let's say I have 3 friends: Homer, Carl and Lenny.

I made a comment on a party meme like: "@homer this party looks amazing!"

Then I remember to tag my other friends, so I edit the comment.

The comment now says: "@homer @carl @lenny this party looks amazing!"

Do @carl and @lenny get notified about that or will only @homer hear about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Think about it, have you ever seen a notification on facebook "(NAME) Edited a post on facebook" ? This can lead to lots of nefarious stuff. You could post something innocuous, get loads of positive responses and then change your post to something wicked and make it look like the commenters like wickedness! :D